# Flutter Firebase Query on nested value in subcollection

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I am looking for a way to query a stream based on information in a subcollection.

Here is an example:

I have a Subcollection of Tickets. Each Ticket has a Subcollection of Companies involved in this Ticket. Each Company has a CEO as a Map. This Map has a field "id".

I now want to query the following thing:
Get me a stream of all tickets where a company in this Ticket has a CEO with id "X".

I tried the following:
refToTickets.where('companies.ceo.id', isEqualTo: CEOId).snapshots();

This doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: You need to get the ref to the subcollection of a given ticket first, instead of refToTickets

Comment: How should that work? I need to get the set of all tickets. The only way that would work would be to first check each ticket and then get a stream on each ticket and combine it into a list afterward. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I see, I thought you wanted the companies. Hold on, I'll look into this for you!

Comment: @Dominic thank you, for your effort. Somebody already told me, that it doesn't work the way I intended it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore queries can only filter on values that are present in the documents that they return. So you can't filter tickets on values from the companies in the subcollection.

As usual when dealing with NoSQL databases, you'll want to modify/expand your data model to allow the use case. Here for example, you could store the company CEOs in a single array field for each ticket and query on that. So each time you write/delete a document, you also update the `companyCEOs` field in the corresponding ticket.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I thought so, but I had hoped that it could work somehow without needing a new field.